VBA Loop to Check Logs
My codes are running fine. But i want to add some conditional if I can check in the Sheet(Logs) From Column E that was logged has a duplicate. The Macro will not Run and it will add it into Logs Sheet. This is my codes in adding Logs.
Sub AddLogs()
'Add to ControlSheet
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim shLogs As String
Dim Rate As String
Dim WSDATA As Worksheet
Dim WSFormat As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim myRange, f As Range
Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WSDATA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFP")
LastRow = WSDATA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastRow
scode = WSDATA.Range("A" & i)
If scode <> "" Then
shLogs = "Logs"
nextrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

End If
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("A" & nextrow).Value = nextrow - 1
'Prepared
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("B" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("C16").Value
'DATE
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("D" & nextrow).Value = Format(WSDATA.Range("B1").Value, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
'CONTROL NUMBER
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("E" & nextrow).Value = "FSS-2024-" & Format(WSDATA.Range("B" & i), "00000")
'PAYEE
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("G" & nextrow).Value = UCase(WSDATA.Range("H" & i).Value)
'BANK
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("H" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("I" & i).Value
'ACCOUNT NUMBER
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("I" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("J" & i).Value
'AMOUNT
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("J" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("D" & i).Value
'PARTICULARS
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("K" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("K" & i).Value
'CORPORATION
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shLogs).Range("L" & nextrow).Value = WSDATA.Range("L" & i).Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next i

End Sub

Have you tried the code? Is it failing to skip the rows that you want it to skip? Is it skipping successfully but failing to add to the log?

Already solved the issue. My problem was. It will log even if there is a duplicate in the sheet("Log").
